# I cannot disable auto-INDENT in VB.NET 2017 Pro Text Editor, on Windows-10 Pro

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Whenever I change the indentation of this code example, after I move the cursor beyond the lines that are just indented, the indentation snaps back to the previous indent.

For example, if I change indent on line:

```
    <DllImport("InhecoMTCdll.dll")>
```

..and then move the cursor off the line, it snaps back to the previous indent.

```
' This interfaces to the DLL (Visual-C++ 'unmanaged' InhecoMTCdll.dll) that interfaces with the Inheco Thermoshake.

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Inheco_Thermoshake_interface

  Public Class NativeMethods

    ' Function within DLL:  
    ' Public int FindTheUniversalControl(int ID);
    ' Corresponging VB.NET declaration:
    <DllImport("InhecoMTCdll.dll")>
    Public Shared Sub FindTheUniversalControl(ByRef ID As Int32 As Int32

    End Sub  

  End Class

End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Tools menu > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Adv.. > Editor Help section > Pretty..  = OFF